# Scid Vs. PC | Using Stockfish on Linux

Tags: engines, software, stockfish, scid

I have downloaded Stockfish 16 from their site at:

https://stockfishchess.org/

Using the command line in linux (I'm a newb), I have compiled it in the 'src' folder. After this, the exec file appears and Stockfish appears to run fine in the command line.

But when I go into Scid Vs. PC and try to add Stockfish as an Engine, it does not detect it.I get a notification that reads:

**The analysis engine terminated without exit code: ""**

I have tried several different command & directory pathing combinations, including using the program to browse directly to the exec itself to avoid error. No success.

Anyone have any suggestions? I've been through several sites and keep seeing variations of my issue but no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have a Linux machine, but like you, I do not know too much about Linux. Everything depends on the version of Linux that you are using. What I did was to search on YouTube. I found a video that guided me step by step.  The following link is a search for STOCKFISH LINUX INSTALL SCID: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stockfish+linux+install+scid

It would be better if you use STOCKFISH UBUNTU INSTALL SCID, if you are using Ubuntu.

Something interesting is that newer versions of Stockfish or Linux do not change too much the process of installation.

So, YouTube is your Salvation Army!

Good luck!

P.S. I noticed that you are using SCID vs PC. Most likely, the same will work for that option. If you do not find one for that purpose, use SCID instead of SCID vs PC for the search of information. They are connected programs.

P.S.#2 Additionally, you can go to the following question, and ask to the people who answered it: [Why can't I put Stockfish in SCID?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14675/why-cant-i-put-stockfish-in-scid?rq=1)